# Specialised template return/set an enum value based on the variable type

Tags: c++, templates, enums, c++14

If I have an enum defined as ...

```
enum MyValue
{
  Unk,
  A,
  B
};
```

I want to create a specialised template that return/set the type based on the variable type itself

```
template<typename T>
struct get_value
{
  // the 'value' should be MyValue::Unk 
};

template<>
struct get_value<int>
{
  // the 'value' should be MyValue::A 
};

template<>
struct get_value<double>
{
  // the 'value' should be MyValue::B 
};
```

That way I could call the struct

```
auto x = get_value<char>::value; // == MyValue::Unk
```

And

```
auto y = get_value<int>::value; // == MyValue::A
```

Is that possible in c++, if so, how could it be achieved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the following:

```
template<typename T>
struct get_value
{
  static constexpr MyValue value = MyValue::Unk;
};

template<>
struct get_value<int>
{
  static constexpr MyValue value = MyValue::A;
};

template<>
struct get_value<double>
{
  static constexpr MyValue value = MyValue::B;
};
```

[Demo](http://ideone.com/jLbpMb)

Answer (score 1):

C++14 adds [Variable templates](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/variable_template), you can use them too:

```
namespace get_value {
    template<typename T>
    constexpr MyValue value = MyValue::Unk;

    template<>
    constexpr MyValue value<int> = MyValue::A;

    template<>
    constexpr MyValue value<double> = MyValue::B;
}
```

They are used a bit different, though:

```
int main() {
    std::cout << get_value::value<char> << std::endl;
    std::cout << get_value::value<int> << std::endl;
    std::cout << get_value::value<double> << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: This works great, I guess it is a matter of style/tast, but in this case I prefer the other method.